# How do I link my one CSS file to all my HTML files which are in different folders?

Tags: css, go, go-fiber

I tried accessing CSS from the parent folder in order for it to be the only CSS file. I get an error when trying to access it.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

```
app.Static("/", "static/home")
# static/home has index.html
app.Static("/signup", "static/signup", #options)
# static/signup has signup.html
```

My CSS works fine when I put it in a folder selected by `app.Static`. However I want just 1 CSS file that all of my html files can access. Therefore I would like it in the static folder but for some reason my HTML files can't access it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
# Both files have this link tag
```

I'm guessing the issue is that I am approaching the problem wrong and app.Static can't see outside of the folder it selects?

Answer (score 0):

The link’s `href` attribute should be an absolute path:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
```

Since the HTML files loaded in the browser will have a path starting with `/signup`, the relative resource path `../style.css` might not always be a reference to `/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is possible.

Assuming this structure:

```
├── main.go
└── static
    ├── home
    │   └── index.html
    └── style.css
```

You just need to set `./static` as root folder.

```
app.Static("/", "static")
```

Then into `./static/home/index.html` use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
```

Doing that, you can go to `http://localhost:3000/home`
and see the content of `./static/home/index.html` using `./static/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of how a web server is meant to be was wrong. I thought every single file was meant to be served form `app.Static` but that only really works for a single page application.

It's best to keep your CSS/JS in there so you can easily call it like `style.css` from your HTML files being served on your standard routes.